# Understanding polymorphic associations the right way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, polymorphic-associations, model-associations

I've tried to set up a polymorphic association in an app, but when I test it out, I seem to be able to retreive my association only from one way:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :category_associations, :as => :categorized
end

class CategoryAssociation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :categorized, :polymorphic => true
end
```

Now, in console, I created some CategoryAssociations (one being @ca ) and an Event ( @e ).
I could then do

```
@ca.categorized = @e
@ca.save
```

My problem is, if I load my event and try a `@e.category_associations` I get an empty array ... but when I try loading my @ca and do a `@ca.categorized`, I get my event !!

Are polymorphic associations one way only ?
Or what am I missing ?

Comment: Why aren't you saving `@ca`?

Comment: Sorry @tadman , you're right, it was a typo ! I corrected it, Thanks !

Comment: Follow-up question is then if the `CategoryAssociation` record is saved correctly or not. Remember, always look at the queries generated in `log/development.log` to see if they make sense.

Comment: Yes, it is: I can even get Event through `CategoryAssociation.first.categorized` !

Comment: If both `@e` and `@ca` are saved, this should be working. What query does the `@e.category_associations` generate? I think your problem's there.

Comment: I can't get any SQL request: each time I request it from console, I get the empty array result without any new log line :/

Comment: It's usually best to put this sort of thing into model tests so you can verify the functionality not only right now, but going forward when you're making changes. That also makes it easy to run and re-run code to ensure it's working correctly. As to why it's not generating a query, that seems odd. You're using the current version of Rails?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not allowed to spend time on tests :/  (Just to waste some on not-working code...)
I'm using Ruby 2.0.0p594 and Rails 3.2.13

Comment: Tests aren't a waste of time if they get things done quicker. Even a throw-away test would save you a lot of hassle here vs. running and re-running code in the console. You probably want to patch that Rails as well, I'm pretty sure 3.2.13 is dangerously vulnerable and 3.2.21 is current. A service like [Gem Canary](http://gemcanary.com/) helps a ton with this sort of maintenance. In any case, that code *should* generate a query.

Comment: Ho no, sorry, I used "waste" on not-working code and "spend" on tests: I'm VERY convinced of tests !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to tadman questions, especially the one asking me to check my ruby version, I had to quit my console and restart it.
I didn't do anything else but my association is now both ways !

I'm gonna try to reproduce this but for now, my problem is solved...

Comment: Ah, of course. In the console you'll need to call `reload!` if you change your models.